# Can't save spark df to impala

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, impala

I'm trying to complete following steps:

1. Load df from impala to jupyter notebook (spark df, one string column, 100 000 rows)
2. Processing another column using pyspark udf, now we have df with two columns (data type - string)
3. Save result (df with two columns) to impala using df.write.format("parquet").saveAsTable

Aquiring error on step 3, can't save new df to impala.

Types of error:

- EOF: read didn't return enough bytes;
- unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes;
- task failed while writing rows (json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string started at line 3 column 116133)

NOTE: there is NO error when i'm trying to complete all three steps with lower data (10 000 rows)

My spark session settings:

```
.config('spark.driver.memory', '20g')/
.config('spark.executor.cores', 2)/
.config('spark.executor.memory', '20g')/
.config('spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled', True)/
.config('spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors', 20)/
.config('spark.yarn.executor. memoryOverhead', '4095')/
.config('spark.serializer', 'org.apache.spark.serializer. Kryoserializer')
```

What can be wrong? Maybe i need some additional settings to spark session?

Thanks

I'm trying to change spark session settings, but udf working quite ok, about 5 min on action (df.show). Don't understand why jvm can't save df to impala

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind sharing some examples of the data you are trying to save, along with the UDF operation? I would try to check if the UDF is being able to apply the transformation correctly over all your data because at glance it looks like part of your data is not being correctly encoded. Additionally, You may also try dividing your 100k rows into 10k mini-batches to check if the problem is really with the workload on your side or with the Impala.

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean "part of your data not being correctly encoded"? It happens after udf processing?

Comment: Normally udfs are like black boxes, so if something breaks it is really hard to track the results. I'm assuming that your udf is picking up the string column and transforming it to something else, so check if part of your data is being corrupted or if you need to enforce some encoding like UTF-8 before writing.